# $(this) not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to dynamically change the name of button value using `this`.
Here is my code.

HTML

```
<input class='submit' id='id1' type='button' value='Submit' />
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit').click(function () {
        $(this).val("hello");
    });
});
```

When I use:

```
$("#id1").val("hello")
```

it's giving expected results.

I have put the same code on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pf92v/

and it works fine there. So what would be the reason behind it? I am using jQuery v1.4

Comment: The input doesn't have a submit class. you aren't even reaching the `$(this)` line.

Comment: What are "unexpected results"? If you've confirmed that the code works on jsFiddle, then why not post some additional code that may demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @KevinB..See EDIted code above

Comment: @amnotiam..same code does not work on my machine.so what would be the possible reason behind it?

Comment: @nikhil: If you've confirmed that the code works on jsFiddle, then why not post some additional code that may demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine, even with [JQuery 1.4.1](http://jsfiddle.net/pf92v/1/) (which was the earliest version I could find) - so your problem must be somewhere else. Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: Could be anything. The base case which you have shown above works. Without seeing more information I don't think you are going to get anything more than down votes. Try putting exactly what you have above in a test page on your server. Then add more of your app to that test page. It's slow but in the end you will either get a working app or know mow about what is breaking. Check firebug/dev tools to see if there is a js error on the case that doesn't work...

Comment: @nikhil are you preventing the form submit so that the page doesn't refresh, making it appear as though the value never changed?

Comment: @MattBurland..i have checked it in firebug..its not giving any errors

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
$('.submit')
```

by

```
$('#id1')
```

The thing is that in your `click` handler, `this` refers to the element clicked. You had defined the click event on elements of class `submit` (that's what `$('.submit')` means). Since not element of class `submit` was found, the handler was never fired.

Answer (score 1):

Your button should have the class "submit"

**EDIT:** You have changed the code in your question and have the class set to submit. In that case, your code should work just fine. If not, there's probably something else wrong, but you'd need to show us some more code.